# CXF DynamicClientFactory efficiency

Tags: performance, web-services, jax-ws, cxf, webservice-client

I need to generate Java client for web service. I have two choices to do that one is use Apache CXF `DynamicClientFactory` class and the other is use JAX-WS Dispatch API.

From CXF documentation I understood that `DynamicClientFactory` class will generate the web service SEI, data classes at runtime (using wsdl2Java tool). If I want to call any web service method I need to load the appropriate data class name and I needs to set the parameter using reflection like follows.

```
JaxWsDynamicClientFactory dcf = JaxWsDynamicClientFactory.newInstance();
Client client = dcf.createClient("people.wsdl", classLoader);

Object person = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass("com.acme.Person").newInstance();

Method m = person.getClass().getMethod("setName", String.class);
m.invoke(person, "Joe Schmoe");

client.invoke("addPerson", person);
```

In the above code `Person` class is generated at runtime by CXF and reflection is used to set the property values.

My question here is: **if I want to set 20 parameter values, then I needs to make 20 reflection call to do that. Is this an efficient way to do that? Or is there any alternative? Or is better to use Dispatch API from JAX-WS?** Please help me.